# Error handling in a Mock Api Using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

im doing a test using retrofit and a mock api, i have already a recyclerview with a list of products and the detail of the product while clicking on the row, but in some products the josn is a error handling example :

```
http://mocklab.io/product/1/
{
  "success": true,
  "metadata": {
    "sku": "2",
    "name": "Huawei P20 Pro",
    "max_saving_percentage": 30,
    "price": 13996,
    "special_price": 7990,
    "brand": "Huawei",
    "rating": {
      "average": 4,
      "ratings_total": 265
    },
```

but lets say in my case product "3" give me the error json :
http:mocklab.io/product/3/

```
{
  "success": false,
  "messages": {
    "error": {
      "reason": "PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND",
      "message": "Product not found!"
    }
  }
}
```

the pojos are already done with jsonschema2pojo, so the question is if i click in the 3 row in the recyclerview my app crash because and i get null object reference, but what i want is to hadle the error they ask that is : HTTP 200 - Success false , sorry if i didnt explain myself the best way, and thank you!
call:

```
    GetPhoneDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetPhoneDataService.class);

        Call<APIReponse> call = service.getAllPhones(1);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<APIReponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<APIReponse> call, Response<APIReponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    for (Result result : response.body().getMdata().getResults()) {
                        phoneList.add(result);

                    }
                    adapter.setOnClickListener(new PhonesAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(int position) {
                            String sku = phoneList.get(position).getSku();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("sku", sku);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    try {
                        String error = response.errorBody().string();

                        if (error != null) {
                            Log.e("Error : ", error);
                        }
                        //show error to the user

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit you can handle errors response like this. Inside `onResponse` callback:

```
                   if (response.isSuccessful()
                    && response.body() != null) {

               //Call was successful and body has data
            } else {
                    try {
                        String error = response.errorBody().string();

                        if(error != null)
                        //show error to the user

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

But if your error is thrown here:

```
 public void onItemClick(int position) {
            String sku = phonesList.get(position).getSku();
            Log.e("ffff", "----- " + sku);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("sku", sku);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

then you have problems with not designing your code very well. I don't know context of your code more precisely context when you call `generatePhonesList` method but, if you need to call it more then once, then consider not setting `adapter` and `recyclerview` inside that method. For that you have something called: `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: thank you, i edited the recyclerview, if want to see, my problem is that, the JSON of the product number 3 its different, so my app crash